# Casting multimap from Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap

Tags: java, guava

I am doing

```
private TreeMultimap<Integer, String> top10words = 
    Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap(TreeMultimap.create());
```

But I get

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from SortedSetMultimap to TreeMultimap

What should I be doing here? I tried casting but that failed

```
private TreeMultimap<Integer, String> top10words = 
    (TreeMultimap<Integer, String>) Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap(TreeMultimap.create());
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve here? the method you're calling returns a `SynchronizedSortedSetMultimap` instead of a `TreeMultimap`, it's wrapping it with a mutex- you can't cast it back.

Comment: A `TreeMultimap` is a `SortedSetMultimap`, but not all `SortedSetMultimap`s are `TreeMultimap`s.

Comment: Try this one:
 `TreeMultimap<Integer, String> t =(TreeMultimap<Integer, String>) Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap((TreeMultimap)TreeMultimap.create());`

Comment: or
`private TreeMultimap<Integer, String> top10words =(TreeMultimap) Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap(TreeMultimap.create());`

Comment: Genrics are doing the problem here

Comment: @RAHULROY The latter won't work.

Answer (score 2):

What you should really do is look at type hierarchy for [`TreeMultimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v24.0/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.java#L75) and note that

- it extends `AbstractSortedKeySortedSetMultimap`
- which extends `AbstractSortedSetMultimap`
- which implements `SortedSetMultimap`.

The latter (`SortedSetMultimap`) is what is returned (actually it's [`SynchronizedSortedSetMultimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v24.0/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Synchronized.java#L867) - an internal Guava class), not `TreeMultimap` (which **isn't** synchronized) and that's why only

```
SortedSetMultimap<Integer, String> top10words =
    Multimaps.synchronizedSortedSetMultimap(TreeMultimap.create());
```

is possible.